# How to get a better email error in ZF2 using Forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I am wondering how to change the email error message returned from a form:

[image]

The error in the image is pretty ugly.

This is my form:

```
    $this->add(
        [
            'name'       => 'email',
            'type'       => 'email',
            'options'    => [
                'label' => 'E-Mail',
                'instructions' => 'Your email address'

            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-element',
                'required' => 'required',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Would be nice for the message to state: "That email is already registered" or "Email me@example.com is already in use"

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way of validating emails for registration. It will strip all tags, trim the email, see if the input field is empty, if the email is at least 5 chars long and if the email contains only valid chars.

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        [
            "name"=>"email",
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'StripTags'],
                ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
            ],
            "validators" => [
                [
                    'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'messages' => ['emailAddressInvalidFormat' => "Email address doesn't appear to be valid."],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 5,
                    ],
                ],
                ['name' => 'NotEmpty'],
            ],
        ],
     ];
}
```

If you simply want to check for existing email inside your database, I would suggest you to do this in your controller, when the form has been submitted and return error/success message depending if the email is there or not. For this you can try this code.

```
$email = 'me@example.com';
$emailQuery = $db->findEmail('email = ?', $email);
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    [
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'email',
        'exclude' => $emailQuery 
    ]
);

if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
    // email appears to be valid
} else {
    // email is invalid; print the reason
    $messages = $validator->getMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. This clears up a number of issues. Generally I use the ObjectExists in the Form but this can cause a headache...